# Any way to change font size

Tags: 16.04, fonts, appearance

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Is there any way to change default font in **all** windows? Like change it's *default* fonts (like size or make title string non bold)?

Answer (score 1):

Well I recommend to install gnome-tweak-tool. Its a GUI software, has many features to customize your Ubuntu. You can search and install it via Software center.

Comment: Ubuntu has one by default, no need for external programs.

Comment: Well I am aware of default features but I said I recommend .....

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu settings:

Menu > Settings Manager > Appearance > Fonts (See picture)

[image: picture]

Comment: This is Xubuntu right .